# PreloadJS - preload and append

Tags: javascript, jquery, createjs, preloadjs

I made a script where provided image list will load all up, working like it should. Now this is my main question:

If I want to use this for let's say portfolio site where I want all project images, site background etc.. to preload and append image to place where they are in html, is there some solution already in preloadjs or do I have to let's say go trough whole page, get image sources and append to every single one of them? And is it possible to combine maybe to preload some assets you use in css or am I asking the impossible or rather hard to do? If any of this is possible, you don't have to send me code, just steps how you would do it (though code wouldn't hurt me).

Maybe I just don't understand for what exactly preloadjs is, I can't find really examples that will be useful to me so I ask here, maybe someone is willing to help me :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

PreloadJS will load assets for you to do what you want with them.

- Images, audio, CSS, and other types are preloaded, and references provided so you can do what you want/need
- Scripts are appended to the page body automatically

Have a look at the samples that come with PreloadJS, which show you how content can be loaded and used: https://github.com/CreateJS/PreloadJS/

Simple example:

```
var queue = new createjs.LoadQueue();
queue.on("complete", handleComplete);
queue.loadManifest([
    {src:"image.png", id:"image"},
    {src:"script.js", id:"script"}
]);
function handleComplete(event) {
    // Put the image into the body.
    document.body.appendChild(queue.getResult("image"));
}
```

Hope that provides some help. PreloadJS assumes some knowledge of working with assets and the DOM in JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you. So if I want now to preload all images for website, I'm gonna have to put their path first in manifest, load them up and append them to where they should be? I can see this really useful for let's say some web game where you usually work a lot with DOM with JS but I don't see it very practical for loading assets for website... I tried jquery html5 loader, but it doesn't have loading progress as I'd want but this script does practically better for websites, in my opinion at least. Please correct me if I'm wrong :) Thank you again

Comment: If you use tag loading, you can lay out your site as-is, and images should pull from the cache. The main challenge is ensuring your preload code fetches the image, and not the DOM.